# The probability that exactly / at-least $k$ numbers are in the correct position

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Given a sequence of $[1,\dots,n]$ in random order:

- Let $P_k$ be the probability that **exactly** $k$ numbers are in the correct position
- Let $Q_k$ be the probability that **at least** $k$ numbers are in the correct position

How can we calculate $P_k$ and $Q_k$?

These are the facts that I've managed to establish so far:

- $P_n=\frac{1}{n!}$
- $P_{n-1}=0$
- $P_k=Q_k-Q_{k+1}$
- $Q_n=P_n$
- $Q_{n-1}=Q_n$
- $Q_k=\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n}P_i$

Partial answers (for example: $P_0,P_1,Q_1$) or any other insights will also be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9484/number-of-permutations-with-a-specified-number-of-fixed-points

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers

Comment: As a check, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} P_k =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} k P_k  = \frac12 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}  Q_k = n!$

Comment: @Henry: Thank you. So this link gives the answer for $P_k$. But it's a recursive answer, where you need to calculate $P_{n-k}$ first. Does that mean that there is no "straight-forward formula" answering this question?

Comment: I only offered my sums as a check

Comment: $\displaystyle P_k = {n \choose k} \times \text{round}\left[\frac{(n-k)!}{e}\right]$, except $P_n=1$

Comment: @Henry $P_n=1$? and $\sum_{k=0}^{n}P_{k}=n!$? $P_{n}=\frac{1}{n!}$ and$\sum_{k=0}^{n}P_{k}=1$. There must be some misunderstanding here.

Comment: @Henry: I referred to the Wikipedia link (not to the sum).

Comment: @drhab: Divide my numbers by $n!$